# Inner product and orthogonal

Tags: integration, inner-products, orthogonality

Let  = [−1,1] with the inner product 〈, 〉 = ∫()() (-1,1)

= { ∈ | (−) = ()}.

Show that ⊥ = { ∈ | (−) = −()}.

Anyone can help me?

I tried this

〈, 〉 = ∫()() (-1,1)

= ∫h(x)  (-1,1)
=∫h()dx(-1,0)  +   ∫h()(0,1)

=-∫h()dx(0,-1) +  ∫h()(0,1)

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g \in W^\top$. $g$ is the sum of its even and odd part:
$$
g(x)=\frac{g(x)+g(-x)}{2} + \frac{g(x)-g(-x)}{2}.
$$
We get
$$
0=\int_{-1}^1 g(x) \frac{g(x)+g(-x)}{2} dx
$$
$$
=\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{g(x)+g(-x)}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{g(x)^2-g(-x)^2}{4} dx
$$
$$
=\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{g(x)+g(-x)}{2}\right)^2 dx.
$$
Hence $g(x)+g(-x)=0$. Note that
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{g(x)^2-g(-x)^2}{4} dx = 0
$$
as the integrand is odd. Reversely if $g$ ist odd and $f$ is even, then
$gf$ is odd and
$$
\int_{-1}^1 g(x)f(x) dx = 0
$$